# How do I better read man pages?

Tags: man

How do I search `man` pages for options? I currently do this:

`/-<option>`

Example:

To see what `grep -i` does, I do this:

`man grep`
and then
`/-i`.

Or, I can do this:

`man grep | grep .-i`

Is there a better way of searching `man` pages for options?

Comment: Not really, but you could make an alias for `man | less -p <PATTERN>` like http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/can-i-get-individual-man-pages-for-the-bash-builtin-commands

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the man output to gedit and then use "ctrl+F" to find whatever you want to.

```
man grep | gedit
```

which will show you man page of grep in a gedit window. Use find option. :)

Comment: How is this remotely better than using grep!

Comment: @CohenK gedit gives you find (ctrl+f) option where you can place search items exactly the way you want. You will not have to remember regex way of searching it or piping it through less/more/grep etc. I would not claim it as "better" way than using grep, but rather I would say this is another work around. Choices may differ :) .

Comment: What's the point of doing all this when you can just search pressing `/` and typing?! Learning the Vim basics will help you move around `man` :)