# How to filter any part of description or option from manpage

Tags: command-line, text-processing, man

I want to get output of any desired description or option from a man page.

Example: I want to get the description for the autoclean option from the `apt-get` man page:

Please suggest a command, something like `man apt-get | <somecommands> autoclean` to get this output:

```
autoclean
           Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. The difference is that it only removes package files that can no longer be downloaded, and are
           largely useless. This allows a cache to be maintained over a long period without it growing out of control. The configuration option APT::Clean-Installed will prevent installed
           packages from being erased if it is set to off.
```

I've tried `man apt-get | grep autoclean` but it is limited to out-put matching lines for word `autoclean` so I can't get full description and seems it is not that what I want!

Hence, Help me to filter part from man-page for expected output mentioned above.

<sup>(Here `apt-get` and `autoclean` is only used as example I am asking this question because when man-page is too long then filtering by such way is very helpful for getting exact thing)</sup>

Comment: See also [Can I get individual man pages for the bash builtin commands?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/can-i-get-individual-man-pages-for-the-bash-builtin-commands) and its duplicate for different approaches.