# less pattern - endswith [ ] or $

Tags: regular-expression, man, less, newlines

Refer to [can-i-get-individual-man-pages-for-the-bash-builtin-commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18092/64403):

```
bashman () { man bash | less -p "^       $1 "; }
```

This function will jump to the desired bash manual parameter section directly.

I want to make it accept any Manual Name and Manual Parameter on the fly, so i change this function to:

```
function superman () {
    man "$1" | less -p "^[ ]+[-]*$2[ ]"
}
```

It works perfectly with:

> $ superman bash type

And jump to the desired man page section:

[image]

But it doesn't work in section ending with newline. I need change it to:

```
function superman () {
    man "$1" | less -p "^[ ]+[-]*$2$"
}
```

Then run `$ superman gcc Wall` will able jump to `Wall` parameter:

[image]

How to combine `[ ]` and `$` to be `[ ] OR $`? i.e. **endswith at "atleast one space" OR "newline"**.

I tried `$ man gcc | less -p "^[ ]+[-]*Wall[ |$]"` but it doesn't works.

Please note that i accept for this undesired jump, which is endswith `[ ]` but not really a beginning of section, because i believe it's unsolvable if regex is `[ ]` OR `$`:

[image]

**[Thanks for answers]**

I want to share my final form here:

```
function superman () {
    if [[ "$1" == "-I" || "$1" == "-i" ]]; then
        man "$2" | less -I -p "^[ ]+-*$3( |=|,|$|\[)"
    else
        man "$1" | less -p "^[ ]+-*$2( |=|,|$|\[)"
    fi
}
```

This will work if i run `superman -i gcc wl` which means case-insensitive to jump into `-Wl,option` section. `-Wl,option` from `gcc` require `,`. `scaletempo` from `mplayer` require `[`, and `scale` from `mplayer` require `=`

I wrote for `info` version too:

```
function superinfo () {
    if [[ "$1" == "-I" || "$1" == "-i" ]]; then
        info "$2" | less -I -p "^ *‘*'*-*\** *$3’*( |=|,|$|\[|:|')"
    else
        info "$1" | less -p "^ *‘*'*-*\** *$2’*( |=|,|$|\[|:|')"
    fi
}
```

Tested with `superinfo gcc _HPPA`, `superinfo -i gcc werror`, `superinfo -i gcc wl`, `superinfo -i mplayer scaletempo`, `superinfo -i mplayer stats`, `superinfo -i ls -f`, and `superinfo -i bash -a`(with minus sign make big difference here). Unicode's LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK `’` used by `-f` of `ls`.

Comment: Nice.  My similar function is just `b () { LESS="+/^ *$*" man bash;}` so I can do, for instance, `b history expansion`.

Comment: How about using `info` where the data is properly indexed. Like `info bash type`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for reminding me, I wrote for `info` version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are mistaken about the meaning of `[` square brackets `]` in a regular expression. Note your pattern:

```
^[ ]+[-]*Wall[ |$]
```

`[ ]` is just exactly the same as  (a single space) and `[-]` is just exactly the same as `-`. And in the final part of the pattern, `[foo|bar]` does not signify "either `foo` or `bar`".

What you're looking for is `( |$)`. That's the syntax for matching one thing OR another thing. (You'll also need to quote that part of the pattern with single quotes or a backslash instead of double quotes, because of the dollar sign).

`[thing]` denotes a character class: it matches either `t`, `h`, `i`, `n`, or `g`.

Comment: Thanks. But what do you means by `quote that part of the pattern with single quotes or a backslash` ? I put `man "$1" | less -p "^[ ]+[-]*$2( |$)"` and works fine, neither have single quotes nor backslash.

Comment: You have a literal `$` in there, so it should be quoted. I guess it "happens" to work by luck in this case because the `$` is followed by something that cannot refer to a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

> How to combine `[ ]` and `$` ?

`([ ]|$)` or `( |$)`