# How to automatically scroll to requested command when the "General Commands Manual" is shown?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, man, less

I sometimes end up requesting the man page for a "basic" command like `set` or `pushd` that is built-in into the bash/zsh shell.

So I type:

```
man set
```

…and I end up here:

```
BASH_BUILTINS(1)            General Commands Manual           BASH_BUILTINS(1)

NAME
       bash,  :,  .,  [, alias, bg, bind, break, builtin, caller, cd, command,
       compgen, complete, compopt,  continue,  declare,  dirs,  disown,  echo,
       enable,  eval,  exec, exit, export, false, fc, fg, getopts, hash, help,
       history, jobs, kill, let, local, logout, mapfile, popd, printf,  pushd,
       pwd,  read, readonly, return, set, shift, shopt, source, suspend, test,
       times, trap, true, type, typeset, ulimit, umask, unalias, unset, wait -
       bash built-in commands, see bash(1)

BASH BUILTIN COMMANDS
       Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented in this section
       as accepting options preceded by - accepts -- to signify the end of the
       options.   The  :, true, false, and test builtins do not accept options
       and do not treat -- specially.  The exit, logout, return,  break,  con‐
       tinue,  let,  and shift builtins accept and process arguments beginning
       with - without requiring --.  Other builtins that accept arguments  but
       are  not  specified  as accepting options interpret arguments beginning
       with - as invalid options and require -- to  prevent  this  interpreta‐
       tion.
       : [arguments]
              No  effect;  the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments
 Manual page set(1) line 1 (press h for help or q to quit)
```

…in a thing apparently called "General Commands Manual".

Now the problem is: This man page is **without any value to me**. I mean, it's very nice, well-written and detailed… actually, *very* detailed.

I know, I can search in man pages with `/` thanks to the default pager `less`), but that does not really help here, as such a common word/string as `set` appears often in the command. And yes, I've tried awkward things as putting spaces around, no, this does not help:
[image: in the text "<several spaces>set" is highlighted as I searched for it, but it is just the text at the top-left of a text block that reads "the value of the variable is<line break>set to value., so I just got the beginning of a line break."]

So this is not productive, as I would have been faster searching for this problem online then, than using the man page. With "proper" man pages that do not have hundreds of commands/man pages combined, it would actually have been faster.

What I actually just want is that **when I type `man set` this page opens, but it automatically scrolls to the command I've actually requested** (i.e. `set` in this example).

That said alternative solutions to the problem (like splitting that huge man page, if such a thing is possible?!) are also appreciated.

I would prefer solutions for this problem for bash or zsh (or other shells, if it is such a specific problem.). However, I would obviously prefer a solution that works everywhere.

Comment: If you type `help set`, does it show something more useful?

Comment: Actually, `help set`, `run-help set` (as proposed in the duplicates) or so, *all* present exactly the same as `man` here! Note I am using zsh.

Comment: OK, `bash -c "help set"` may be better. You may want to add the `zsh` tag to attract zsh-specific answers.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Despite whatever strange magic that happens there, **it works**! And yes, I could only add 5 tags, so I had to limit it.

Feel free to post a real answer here… (or wait, ah, you cannot, because it is a dupe – so maybe at the duped question.)